# Can't open X11 applications on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu

I need to enable the scroll lock key on Ubuntu, and for that I need to use Xmodmap, which is part of the X11 tools, but none of the X11 tools work. It just says

```
Unable to open display ''
```

or

```
Can't open display:
```

I'm running Ubuntu on VMware on Windows. When I had the Gnome gui it worked fine but it's not working for the cli. I just need to enable scroll lock I don't see how that's gui related

I even tried to change the display by using export display="localhost" or ":0.0" but that didn't work

Comment: Well, if you're on the CLI without any GUI running, is X11 running? You may need to start your X server for those tools to work.

Comment: I'm not accessing it remotely

Comment: How are you using xmodmap exactly? What configuration do you think "enables Scroll Lock"?

Answer (score 1):

> When I had the Gnome gui it worked fine but it's not working for the cli. I just need to enable scroll lock I don't see how that's gui related

*Generally,* it isn't. But the same subsystem which handles graphics output – Xorg – also handles many advanced mouse/keyboard input features as well, and the *specific feature* you are trying to use – key remapping via Xmodmap – is part of X11 (and therefore Xorg), just as its name says.

For good reason, kernel developers usually resist doing things that userspace could do better. So the kernel only provides basic abstractions – KMS for video, evdev for input – but has only very *minimal* support for advanced features like layouts, key remapping, or even mice, therefore Xorg needs to take care of that just like it takes care of drawing windows and menus.

---

On the other hand, Xmodmap cannot possibly *enable* something that the kernel itself hasn't enabled yet. All it can is *remap* a key to another key. So if <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> doesn't work at the console, you have different problems.

At the Linux console, Scroll Lock already *has* a purpose – it pauses and resumes the console output. If that does not work, you should test it using `evemu-record` (which tests the kernel's evdev layer directly) or `libinput-debug-devices`, to record what key code the kernel itself assigns to it. If you see something unusual, then permanent remappings can be configured [via udev](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/hwdb/60-keyboard.hwdb).